# How to resolve application/octet-stream in S3 using TUS node, Tusd, Uppy or .NET,

Tags: react-native, uppy, tus, tus-js-client, tusdotnet

This is an explanation of a problem, I encountered while uploading files to S3 using **tus-node-server** or **Tusd**.

The problem, is I have a server running tus server and takes requests from react and react native clients. The file gets uploaded successfully from the client to S3, but when I check inside S3 bucket, the content-type is always converted to **application/octet-stream**.

Tried setting the content-type headers but the tus server didn't like that.

In the answer below I explain how to resolve the issue:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it has to be passed as a metadata like this from **tus-js-client** or **uppy** client.

Code looks like this:

**uppy**

```js
       uppy.addFiles({
              name: asset.fileName,
              type: asset.type,
              data: asset,
              meta: {
                name: asset.fileName,
                type: asset.type,
                contentType: asset.type, //This field is how you set content-type, it will be parsed on the tus server automatically and will set the correct content-type
              },
       })
```

**tus-js-client**

```js
        var upload = new tus.Upload({
              name: asset.fileName,
              type: asset.type,
              data: asset,
              meta: {
                name: asset.fileName,
                type: asset.type,
                contentType: asset.type, //This field is how you set content-type, it will be parsed on the tus server automatically and will set the correct content-type
              }
        }, {
        endpoint: "http://localhost:1080/files/",
        retryDelays: [0, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000],
        metadata: {
            filename: file.name,
            filetype: file.type
        },
        onError: function(error) {
            console.log("Failed because: " + error)
        },
        onProgress: function(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
            var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
            console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + "%")
        },
        onSuccess: function() {
            console.log("Download %s from %s", upload.file.name, upload.url)
        }
    })
    
    // Check if there are any previous uploads to continue.
    upload.findPreviousUploads().then(function (previousUploads) {
        // Found previous uploads so we select the first one. 
        if (previousUploads.length) {
            upload.resumeFromPreviousUpload(previousUploads[0])
        }
    
        // Start the upload
        upload.start()
    })
```

Please note that contentType is the key to setting the content-type on the tus server header. The metadata will be decoded and will be set correctly to S3 content-type.